# ps1 works in ise but not in powershell or schedule task

Tags: powershell, monitoring

Im a little crazy right now. I have this ps1 that works perfect in ise but when I execute the same script with powershell or in a schedule task doesn't work. I think it only run once, after that the window closes.
Can anyone help me please?

This is the script that im trying to use in an automatic task:

```
$MonitorFolder = "\\sharedfolder"
$MonitorStopFile = "monitor.die"
$smtpServer = "xxx"
$smtpFrom = "xxx"
$smtpTo = "xxx"
#$smtpSubject = "Asignacion tarea LDA"
$smtpSubject = "Asignacion tarea LDA $($MonitorFolder)."
$smtpPort = "25"

$mailparam =@{
    To = $smtpTo
    From = $smtpFrom
    Subject = $smtpSubject
    Body = $smtpBody
    SmtpServer = $smtpServer
    Port = $smtpPort
    #Credential = $smtpCred
}

$SourceID = "MonitorFiles"
$IncomingFiles = Get-ChildItem $MonitorFolder

$smtp = New-Object -TypeName "Net.Mail.SmtpClient" -ArgumentList $smtpServer

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $MonitorFolder
#Files only. Default is files + directory
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'

$newFileSubscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier NewFileCreated -Action { 
Write-Host "New file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"

$smtpBody += "`n[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named '$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)' arrived in $($MonitorFolder)"

if($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name -eq $MonitorStopFile) {
    Write-Host "Monitoring stopped"
    #Stop monitoring
    Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $newFileSubscription.Id
    #Dispose FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Dispose()
}
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody)      
}
```

Comment: I have ran into something similar in the past. It was because the ISE is loading more than `Powershell.exe` does. I forgot what exactly I used to solve the issue because I found a different way but I believe it was with the `Add-Type` cmdlet

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you give me more details? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the Task with the highest privileges.
This could be the Problem. 
Another possible solution could be:
Try to add the Argument: "powershell.exe -noexit c:\xxxx.ps1" in the Schedule.

The pictures shows the Checkbox.
[Highest Privilegs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9gJi.png)

This Picture Shows the Argument field
[Argument Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VrMp.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Link only answers are discouraged here as links can later change or otherwise end up dead. It would be better to instead describe what solution the link shows via text in your answer. You should be able to click "edit" on your answer to do this.

Comment: yes, I did it without fix the problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks Kevin again, I tried too, but same problem, with this parameter the script runs one time, but it closes after that, for that reason only checks that folder one time. I need that the script doesnt stop.